# i want to enhance my controllers resizer code

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

it is not a problem , more of enhance.
i wrote this to control auto resizing controllers on windows forms form

but when maximizing, the gaps at height are grater that the ratio between old height and new height

```
//width and height control functions

        //at using make sure exists or add:
        //using System.Data;

        // put in form load
        //setinitialsize();

        // put in form resize();
        // newsize();

        DataTable initialsize = new DataTable();
        private void setinitialsize()
        {
            initialsize.Columns.Add("height");
            initialsize.Columns.Add("width");
            initialsize.Columns.Add("top");
            initialsize.Columns.Add("left");
            //initialsize.Columns.Add("control");
            DataRow initialrow = initialsize.NewRow();

            initialrow[0] = (int)this.Height;
            initialrow[1] = (int)this.Width;
            initialrow[2] = 0;
            initialrow[3] = 0;
            //initialrow[4] = this.Name;
            initialsize.Rows.Add(initialrow);

            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                DataRow initialrow2 = initialsize.NewRow();

                initialrow2[0] = (int)c.Height;
                initialrow2[1] = (int)c.Width;
                initialrow2[2] = (int)c.Top; ;
                initialrow2[3] = (int)c.Left; ;
                //initialrow2[4] = c.Name;
                initialsize.Rows.Add(initialrow2);

            }
        }


        private void newsize()
        {

            int n = 1;
            float heightrate = (this.Height / float.Parse(initialsize.Rows[0][0].ToString()));
            float widthrate = (this.Width / float.Parse(initialsize.Rows[0][1].ToString()));

            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                int cHeight = (int)(heightrate * int.Parse(initialsize.Rows[n][0].ToString()));
                if ((cHeight <= this.Height) && (cHeight > 0)) { c.Height = cHeight; }

                int cWidth = (int)(widthrate * int.Parse(initialsize.Rows[n][1].ToString()));
                if ((cWidth <= this.Width) && (cWidth > 0)) { c.Width = cWidth; }

                int cTop = (int)(heightrate * int.Parse(initialsize.Rows[n][2].ToString()));
                if ((cTop >= 0) && ((cTop + cHeight) < this.Height)) { c.Top = cTop; }

                int cLeft = (int)(widthrate * int.Parse(initialsize.Rows[n][3].ToString()));
                if ((cLeft >= 0) && ((cLeft + cWidth) < this.Width)) { c.Left = cLeft; }

                n++;

            }

        }
```

how to enhance this to get smooth resizing and to avoid any un seen issues might happen?

Comment: Why would one convert everything into a string first, just to parse that string into a number again?

Comment: @ThomasWeller you mean at newsize() datatable cell is an object i have to convert to string to parse again as int or float, do you have a better idea ?

Comment: Do you have no abstraction between your database and the user control? When you change the database layout you'll need to change the user interface as well? You can do that, of course...

Comment: Or is that DataTable the code that you really have? And that DataTable never actually faces a database?

Comment: @ThomasWeller i have no database , this will be put on each form code , the data table is loaded with data when form is loaded

Comment: never faces database

Comment: Okay, then please don't do that. Use a List<Dimension> instead. I currently assume that the difference is caused by many resize events and the rounding to int adding up. Don't use Microsoft Rectangle, but some structure that stores doubles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253884/discussion-between-mo-mo-and-thomas-weller).